# How to store integer value with leading zero in decimal form (No octal digit)?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int number = 08;
    printf("%d",number);
    return 0;
}
```

or if it's invalid then why?

Comment: A leading `0` digit in a number is "octal".  And since octal digits only go from `0-7`, `08` isn't valid.

Comment: But numbers are numbers.  They aren't stored in memory any differently regardless if your program works in octal, decimal, or hex.  **What are you really trying to do?**  I suspect you just want to print with a leading zero.  Have you tried: `printf(%02d, number");`

Comment: Decimal constants have to start with a nonzero digit, so you will just have to write `int number = 8;`.  There is no alternative in standard C, see 6.4.4.1(1) of the C17 standard.

Comment: If you must, store `"08"` as a string value and then remove leading zeros and convert to integer when required. Or, better, store as `8` and output with `"%02d"` when needed.

Comment: @selbie I was trying to solve problem 11 from projecteuler, where i got an array with some leading zero's  So I was curious If there's any way to deal with leading zero's.Thanks for your help  .

Comment: `char input[] = "008"; int myint = 0; size_t nzeros = strspn (input, "0"); if (sscanf (&input[nzeros], "%d", &myint) == 1) printf ("input : %s ==> myint : %d\n", input, myint);` NOTE, you can do without the `strspn()` call and just use `if (sscanf (input, "%d", &myint) == 1)` as it will ignore leading zeros on it's own. However if you wanted to know the number of leading zeros, `strspn()` is a simple way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of t[he problem you are solving on Project Euler](https://projecteuler.info/problem=11), the leading `0`'s in that matrix are just decorative padding, not meant to be interpreted as octal or anything else.

So if you are putting together an array/matrix of numbers in your code, just drop the leading zeros from the input set you are copying from.

For example, instead of this hypothetical declaration:

```
int row1[] = {08, 02, 22, 97, 38, 15, 00, 40, 00, 75, 04, 05, 07, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 08};
```

Just change your code declaration to be:

```
int row1[] = {8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 0, 40, 0, 75, 4, 5, 7, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8};
```

That's all you have to do.